# System.Timers.Timer rise event every 5 min

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I need timer to rise event every 5 min but not only 5 min it must be on 00:00, 00:05, 00:10, 00:15 .... 23:55 and again 00:00.

Server will send information every 5 min but when server started he need to calculate how many time is left until first rise of event, after that I cannot set 5 min interval because i lose like that every rise about 3-7 millisecond. so after few day's I lose lot of time. Because that I need to calculate every time rise of event after event is triggered. Because that I got in DB table with times (00:00, 00:05, ... 23:55) when server must rise event, also that table can be changed.

Anny suggestion will help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Alternative to System.Timers.Timer, to call a function at a specific time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699556/c-sharp-alternative-to-system-timers-timer-to-call-a-function-at-a-specific-t)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're about to set the timer's intervall for the next time, you should read the system clock and calculate the remaining time to the next 5-Min "Tick"

Example:

If it is 2:30:10 you should set an intervall of 4 Min, 50 seconds.

Comment: I do that now, but i got about 1000 ms range when I use every time when event rise, its in 1000 ms. Need something in 100 ms at least.

Comment: Well, then raise the event 1 sec ahead of time and do some finer timing inside the event handler, probably with a tight Sleep() loop.